# Derivative (or differential) of symmetric square root of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, derivatives, svd

Let A be a square, symmetric, positive-definite matrix.  Let S be its symmetric square root found by a singular value decomposition.  Let vech() be the half-vectorization operator.

Is there a convenient expression for the derivative (or differential) of vech(S) with respect to vech(A)?

I know the expression for an inverse, which is sort of like a matrix version of the power rule.  Would this approach work for a symmetric square root as well (i.e., (1/2)S^(-1/2))?

Comment: You can easily get an expression for $dS$ in terms of $A$ and $dA$ using the product rule applied to $d(S^2)$. This will involve some matrix multiplication; I'm not sure what the final expression in terms of "half-vectorization" would look like.

Comment: Ah, thanks.  Yes, it amounts to finding d(A), then isolating the d(S) terms.

Answer (score 17):

What follows is an extension of the previous comments, to derive an explicit expression in terms of [Kronecker sum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_addition#Kronecker_sum). Taking differential $\mathrm{d}(\cdot)$ to both sides of $\sqrt{A}\sqrt{A} = A$ results a special case of [Sylvester equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester_equation) 
$$(\mathrm{d}\sqrt{A}) \sqrt{A} \: + \: \sqrt{A} (\mathrm{d}\sqrt{A}) = \mathrm{d}A,
$$
which can be solved for the differential matrix $\mathrm{d}\sqrt{A}$ as 
$$
\text{vec}(\mathrm{d}\sqrt{A}) = \left(\sqrt{A}^{\top} \oplus \sqrt{A}\right)^{-1} \: \text{vec}(\mathrm{d}A).
$$ 
Since $A$ is positive definite, $\sqrt{A}$ is unique and positive definite, and hence the Kronecker sum is positive definite (thus non-singular). Further, since the differential and vec operator can be interchanged in the left hand side of the equation above, the Jacobian identification rule (p. 198 in Magnus and Neudecker, *Matrix Differential Calculus with Applications in Statistics and Econometrics*, 3rd ed., chapter 9, section 5) results
$$
\mathrm{D}\sqrt{A} = \left(\sqrt{A}^{\top} \oplus \sqrt{A}\right)^{-1},
$$
where the transpose can be dispensed if $A$, in addition to being positive-definite, is also symmetric, as the OP asked. Notice that for generic matrix function $F: \mathbb{R}^{p\times q} \mapsto \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$, the Jacobian is defined as $\mathrm{D}F(X) \triangleq \displaystyle\frac{\partial \: \text{vec}(F(X))}{\partial \: (\text{vec}(X))^{\top}}$, and is of size $mn \times pq$.

Comment: Can you explain how did you get $\text{vec}(\mathrm{d}\sqrt{A}) = \left(\sqrt{A}^{\top} \oplus \sqrt{A}\right)^{-1} \: \text{vec}(\mathrm{d}A)$?

Comment: The step before is a special type of [Sylvester equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester_equation) $PX + XQ = R$, whose solution is known to be expressible in vectorized form: $(I \otimes P + Q^{\top} \otimes I) \text{vec}(X) = \text{vec}(R)$. For us, $P = Q = \sqrt{A}$, $X = {\rm{d}}\sqrt{A}$, $R = {\rm{d}}A$. Then use the definition of [Kronecker sum](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/KroneckerSum.html).

Answer (score 10):

The function $A\rightarrow S=\sqrt{A}$ is defined and differentiable on the set of SPD matrices. Let $K=DS_A(H)$ be the derivative of $S$ in $A$, where $H$ is a variable SYMMETRIC matrix. Here $SS=A$ implies $KS+SK=H$, a Sylvester equation in the unknown $K$. We may assume $A=diag((\lambda_i)_i)$ where $\lambda_i>0$. Then $S=diag((\sqrt{\lambda_i})_i)$. If $H=[h_{i,j}],K=[k_{i,j}]$, then, by an easy identification, we obtain $k_{i,j}=\dfrac{h_{i,j}}{\sqrt{\lambda_i}+\sqrt{\lambda_j}}$. Of course, if $n=1$, we find the usual derivative $h_{1,1}\rightarrow \dfrac{h_{1,1}}{2\sqrt{\lambda_1}}$.

EDIT 1. About the half-vectorization operator, we can store half of matrix $K$ because it is symmetric as the matrix $H$.

EDIT 2. Another form of $K$ is $\int_0^{\infty}e^{-tS}He^{-tS}dt$. That implies that if $H$ is a small symmetric matrix, then $\sqrt{A+H}\approx \sqrt{A}+\int_0^{\infty}e^{-t\sqrt{A}}He^{-t\sqrt{A}}dt$.

EDIT 3. Proof of the above result. The integral converges (easy) and it suffices to prove that $KS+SK=H$ (the solution in $K$ of this equation is unique). One has $KS+SK=\int_0^{+\infty}e^{-tS}He^{-tS}S+Se^{-tS}He^{-tS}dt=-\int_0^{+\infty}(e^{-tS}He^{-tS})'dt=H.$

Answer (score 6):

To summarize Abhishek's post
$$\eqalign{
A &= S^2,\quad a={\rm vec}(A),\quad s={\rm vec}(S),\quad M=S^T\oplus S \cr
ds &= M^{-1}\,da \cr
}$$
However, to answer the original question, one must introduce [Duplication and Elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duplication_and_elimination_matrices) matrices.
$$\eqalign{
\alpha &= {\rm vech}(A),\quad \alpha=L_na,\quad a=D_n\alpha \cr
\sigma &= {\rm vech}(S),\quad \sigma=L_ns,\quad s=D_n\sigma \cr
L_n\,ds &= L_nM^{-1}(D_nL_n\,da) \cr
d\sigma &= L_nM^{-1}D_n\,\,d\alpha \cr
\frac{\partial\sigma}{\partial\alpha} &= L_nM^{-1}D_n \cr
}$$