# Concentration of square root of PSD matrix around its mean

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, concentration-of-measure

Suppose $X$ is an $n\times n$ symmetric PSD matrix. If $X$ concentrates around its expected value, i.e. $\|X-\mathbb{E}[X]\|_2\leq \epsilon$ w.h.p, can we conclude that $X^{1/2}$ concentrates around $\mathbb{E}[X^{1/2}]$?

In general, does $X^p$ concentrate around anything?

If not, are there any extra assumptions needed to make this concentration happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes when $\epsilon>0$ is sufficiently small. More specifically, let $E(X)=M$. Using the [uniform continuity](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1940274) of the matrix square root function on the cone of all positive definite matrices (the function is also [differentiable](https://mathoverflow.net/a/193348) on the PSD matrix cone, but this is irrelevant here), $\|X^{1/2}-M^{1/2}\|$ can be made arbitrarily and *uniformly* smaller than any $\delta>0$ whenever $\|X-M\|\le\epsilon$ for a sufficiently small $\epsilon>0$. Hence
$$
\begin{align}
\|X^{1/2}-E(X^{1/2})\|
&=   \|X^{1/2}-M^{1/2} + E(M^{1/2}-X^{1/2})\|\\
&\le \|X^{1/2}-M^{1/2}\| + E\|M^{1/2}-X^{1/2}\|\\
&\le \delta(1+O(\epsilon)).
\end{align}
$$

Comment: What happens to the relative error? i.e. $\|X^{1/2}-E(X^{1/2})\|/\|E(X^{1/2})\|$. Could you also give a bound for that?