# Derivative of the determinant of the right stretch tensor

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, derivatives, determinant, matrix-calculus

I have to evaluate the derivative
$$
\frac{\partial\det\mathcal{U}}{\partial F}
$$
where $\mathcal{U}=\sqrt{F^TF}$ and $F$ is a $m\times n$ real matrix. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

**Thank you all, guys!! You helped me a lot.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also approach the problem using differentials instead of the chain rule. It is easy to work with differentials, because algebraically they act like ordinary matrices.

Define a new matrix variable $W$, and its differential $$\eqalign{
W &= U^2 = F^TF = W^T \cr
dW &= 2\,\operatorname{sym}(F^T\,dF)\cr
}$$where $\operatorname{sym}(A)=\frac{1}{2}\,(A+A^T)$ is the symmetrization operation.

Now you want to find the gradient of
$$\eqalign{
g &= \det(U) = \sqrt{\det W} \cr
}$$
but it's more convenient work with its logarithm instead
$$\eqalign{
h &= \log(g) = \frac{1}{2}\,\log\det W\cr
dh &= d\log(g) = \frac{1}{2}\,d\operatorname{tr}\log W \cr
\frac{dg}{g} &= \frac{1}{2}\,W^{-1}:dW \cr
dg &= \frac{g}{2}\,W^{-1}:dW \cr
   &= g\,W^{-1}:\operatorname{sym}(F^T\,dF) \cr
   &= g\,\operatorname{sym}(W^{-1}):F^T\,dF \cr
   &= g\,W^{-1}:F^T\,dF \cr
   &= g\,FW^{-1}:dF \cr
\cr
}$$ where colon denotes the double-dot (aka Frobenius) product, which can be defined as $$A:B=\operatorname{tr}(A^TB)$$

So the gradient of interest is
$$\eqalign{
\frac{\partial g}{\partial F} &= gFW^{-1} \cr
  &= F(F^TF)^{-1}\det\sqrt{F^TF} \cr
}$$

Comment: Thanks. That`s really like the result I expect. Let me go through!!!!

Comment: However, I can`t understand those two formula.
$$
dh=\frac{1}{2}d\operatorname{tr}\left[\log\left(W\right)\right]
$$
and
$$
\frac{dg}{g}=\frac{1}{2}W^{-1}:dW.
$$
Could you please explain them to me? Many thanks.

Comment: The first one is a corollary of Jacobi's formula $$d\log\det X=d\operatorname{tr}\log X$$The second comes from the logarithmic derivative $$d\log x = \frac{dx}{x}$$ and the differential of the trace of a function $$d\operatorname{tr}f(X)=f^\prime(X^{T}):dX$$

Comment: Are you sure about the first formula? The corollary of Jacobi`s formula I found here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi%27s_formula says that
$$
d\log\det X=\operatorname{tr}d\log X.
$$

Comment: @AsaturKhurshudyan  The trace is linear so $\,\,\,d\operatorname{tr}f=\operatorname{tr}df\,\,\,$

Comment: Could you please explain also how you get
$$
g\,W^{-1}:\operatorname{sym}(F^T\,dF)=g\,\operatorname{sym}(W^{-1}):F^T\,dF?
$$

Comment: The value of the Frobenius product is unchanged if both arguments are transposed $$A^T:B=A:B^T$$ Using this fact $$\eqalign{B:(A+A^T) &= B:A + B:A^T \cr &= B:A + B^T:A \cr &= (B+B^T):A \cr}$$Omitting the factor of $\frac{1}{2}$, this is exactly what the sym() operator is doing.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2125499/second-derivative-of-det-sqrtftf

Answer (score 0):

**Hint.**

Name $f(F) = \det \sqrt{F^T F}$ You can write $f= f_3 \circ f_2 \circ f_1$ as the function composition of

$$\begin{array}{l|rcl}
f_1 : & \mathcal M_{m,n}(\mathbb R) & \longrightarrow & \mathcal S^+(\mathbb R^n) \subseteq \mathcal M_{n}(\mathbb R) \\
    & F & \longmapsto & F^T F \end{array}$$

$$\begin{array}{l|rcl}
f_2 : & \mathcal S^+(\mathbb R^n) & \longrightarrow & \mathcal S^+(\mathbb R^n) \\
    & M & \longmapsto & \sqrt{M} \end{array}$$

$$\begin{array}{l|rcl}
f_3 : & \mathcal M_{n} & \longrightarrow & \mathbb R \\
    & M & \longmapsto & \det M \end{array}$$

And finally

$$\begin{array}{l|rcl}
f : & \mathcal M_{m,n}(\mathbb R) & \longrightarrow & \mathbb R \\
    & F & \longmapsto & \det \sqrt{F^T F} \end{array}$$

You want to compute the Fréchet derivative $f^\prime$ of $f$. Applying the chain rule twice, you have:
$$f^\prime(F)=(f_3^\prime((f_2 \circ f_1)(F))) \circ f_2^\prime(f_1(F)) \circ f_1^\prime(F)$$

Now you have to find the Fréchet derivative of $f_1$, $f_2$ and $f_3$.

You have ([Jacobi Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi%27s_formula)):
$$f_3^\prime(F).H = \text{tr}(\text{adj}(F)H)$$ and (based on the derivative of a bilinear function between vector spaces)

$$f_1^\prime(F).H=F^T H + H^T F$$

The most difficult is to compute $f_2^\prime$. That can be done using [Implicit function theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function_theorem), knowing that
$$(f_2(F))^2=F^T F$$ See [Derivative (or differential) of symmetric square root of a matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/540361/derivative-or-differential-of-symmetric-square-root-of-a-matrix) for more details on that last point.

Comment: Thank you for the hint. It`s still seems to be hard for me to understand.

Comment: @AsaturKhurshudyan $f$  is not a straightforward function by the way!

Comment: What do you think about using $\det G^2=\det^2G$ to write
$$
\frac{\partial\det\sqrt{F^TF}}{\partial F}=\frac{\partial\sqrt{\det F^TF}}{\partial F}=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\det F^TF}}\frac{\partial\det F^TF}{\partial F}.
$$
But I am not sure how to proceed.

Comment: @AsaturKhurshudyan Yes, I think that it is a good idea! You can still use $f_1$, $f_3$ and the chain rule as above to follow on.