# Perturbative expansion of an expression involving the matrix square root

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, taylor-expansion, matrix-calculus, perturbation-theory

Let $A$ and $B$ be Hermitian positive-definite matrices. I am looking for a perturbative expansion of
$$
(A+\epsilon B)^{-1/2}
$$
in orders of $\epsilon$. I suspect such an expansion is possible since for real $a,b$,
$$
(a+\epsilon b)^{-1/2} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{a}}-\epsilon\frac{b}{2 a^{3/2}} + \epsilon^2\frac{3b^2}{8a^{5/2}} + \mathcal{O}(\epsilon^3)
$$
It is not obvious to me how to derive an analogous result for matrices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cf. my answer in   [Derivative (or differential) of symmetric square root of a matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/540361/derivative-or-differential-of-symmetric-square-root-of-a-matrix)

For $A$ symmetric $>0$ and $H$ small symmetric

$(A+H)^{-1/2}=A^{-1/2}-A^{-1/2}\int_0^{+\infty}e^{-t\sqrt{A}}He^{-t\sqrt{A}}dtA^{-1/2}+O(||H||^2)$

When $H=\epsilon B$ where $\epsilon$ is small and $B$ symmetric

$(A+\epsilon B)^{-1/2}=A^{-1/2}-\epsilon A^{-1/2}\int_0^{+\infty}e^{-t\sqrt{A}}Be^{-t\sqrt{A}}dtA^{-1/2}+O(\epsilon ^2)$

Comment: How does the formula change if $A$ is positive semidefinite?

Comment: Then, there is no more formula.

Comment: I want to calculate $\sqrt{A+\epsilon B}$ (not its inverse), but the support of $A$ is smaller than the support of $B$. There is clearly some answer for this question but I am having trouble finding the answer.