# How to calculate derivative of matrix to power 1/2

Tags: derivatives, matrix-calculus

Provided that $\mathbf{B}^{\frac{1}{2}}$ exists, how to calculate $\frac{\text{d}\mathbf{x}^{\text{T}}\mathbf{B}^{\frac{1}{2}}\mathbf{x}}{\text{d}\mathbf{B}}$? $\mathbf{x}$ is a column vector and $\mathbf{B}$ is a square matrix.

Comment: The existence of $B^{\frac{1}{2}}$ doesn't imply the existence of $X^{\frac{1}{2}}$ in e neighborhood of $B$, which is required in order to be able to define the derivative.

Comment: This [related post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/540361) might help.

Comment: @greg Many thanks.